# Рисование оверлея шейдерами (Перехват SwapBuffers) (OpenGL 3.0)

Tags: c++, opengl

Делаю оверлей для игры Java Minecraft на C++ с использованием OpenGL. В snapshot 21w10a игра обновилась до OpenGL Core 3.2, из-за чего вызовы функций типа glBegin, glVertex и так далее, перестали работать. До этого я использовал этот код и всё было хорошо.

```
BOOL WINAPI Client::mySwapBuffers(HDC hDC)
{
    int viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(viewport[0], viewport[2], viewport[3], viewport[1], -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    glEnd();

    glPopAttrib();

    return pSwapBuffers(hDC);
}
```

Я мало в этом разбираюсь, но как объяснил мне один человек, эти функции перестали поддерживаться. Так же он посоветовал использовать функции из OpenGL Core 3.0 и рисовать шейдерами, для того чтобы мой оверлей был виден как на самых старых (при вызове glGetString(GL_VERSION) OpenGL показывал что-то на подобии OpenGL Compatible 4.6) так и на самых новых версиях игры.

Я попытался самостоятельно перенести код на рисование треугольника из [одного учебника](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp) на новую версию OpenGL, но у меня что-то выходит не так. На старых версиях игры, при загрузке моей библиотеки, треугольник рисуется, но потом игра сразу же закрывается. На новой версии игры треугольник ведёт себя крайне странно. Бывает так, что при загрузке моей библиотеки он рисуется, но текст в игре начинает смазываться, а фон пропадает. Бывает так, что он рисуется только 1 раз, а бывает и вовсе не рисуется. При этом всём, код остаётся тем же самым.

```
bool init = false;

const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

unsigned int shaderProgram;
unsigned int VBO, VAO;

BOOL WINAPI Client::mySwapBuffers(HDC hDC)
{
    if (!init)
    {
        init = true;

        if (!gladLoadGL())
        {
            MessageBox(0, L"gladLoadGL error", L"Notify", MB_OK);
        }

        unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);

        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        }

        unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        }

        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

        if (!success)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        float vertices[] =
        {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
             0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
        };

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    return pSwapBuffers(hDC);
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите понять, где я допустил ошибку и объясните как её устранить.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было запомнить

```
int id;
glGetIntegerv(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM, &id);

int id2;
glGetIntegerv(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY_BINDING, &id2);
```

И восстановить их после рисования